# How to cite authors with same surnames?

Tags: citations

How should I use in-text citation in case of **one book** from two authors with same surnames?

For instance; a source from Paul Ehrlich and Anna H. Ehrlich.

Which one is correct?

> " ... " (Ehrlich & Ehrlich, 2015)
>
> " ... " (P. Ehrlich & Ehrlich, 2015)

Comment: Are you familiar with LaTeX?  The language has lots of tools (BibTeX, BibLaTeX, NatBib) for making sure citations turn out correctly.

Answer (score 5):

> - " ... " (Ehrlich & Ehrlich, 2015)
> - " ... " (P. Ehrlich & A. H. Ehrlich, 2015)
> - " ... " (Paul Ehrlich & Anna H. Ehrlich, 2015)

Are all correct. The adopted reference style will dictate which should be used.

Comment: Thanks, I use APA style

Comment: @Shadovx in APA the goal is to make sure the in text citation unambiguously links to a single item in the reference list. In this case it would be the first one. Now if P Erlich wrote a book in 2015 and A Erlich wrote an article in 2015, you would use initials, but if P Erlich wrote two things in 2015, you would use 2015a and 2015b.